# How to fill .NET dataset using an array filter?

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I would like to fill a .NET dataset using a filter of a criteria array.   The dataset is too large to load and filter after loading.   In C#, the fill would look something like:

```
List<int> customerIDs;
...
myAdapter.FillByCustomerIDs(customerIDs);
```

Which would generate the SQL clause

```
  WHERE CustomerID IN (x,x,x)
```

in which the x,x,x comes from the customerIDs array.

I cannot find any way to pass this type of filter to the TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard.

Comment: Can you pass parameter to underlying Command object (and under-underlying query or stored procedure) ?

Comment: The TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard is a toy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL create a  function (note that the `@s` parameter has a length of 1024, which you might want to increase):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(1024))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT 
        CAST(SUBSTRING(@s, start, 
            CASE 
                WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start 
                ELSE 512 
            END) as int) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
  GO
```

and a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCustomerIds]
    @ids nvarchar(max),
    @sep char(1)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM Customers 
    WHERE CustomerId in 
        (SELECT s FROM dbo.Split(@sep,@ids))
RETURN 0
```

In the *TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard*, bind the `FillByCustomerIds` command to the above stored procedure. Now, you may have the following usage:

```
List<int> customerIDs = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
myAdapter
    .FillByCustomerIds(dt, 
    customerIDs.Aggregate<int, string>("", 
        (s, i) => s + i.ToString() + ","), ",");
```